# Multiple Threads in an Azure Worker Role and Storage Queue Access

Tags: azure, azure-queues

I am planning to implement an azure worker role which can start multiple threads. Each thread may want to read from or write to a storage queue. For different worker role instances, race situations are not the case. But, is it safe to simultaneously access the same queue from different threads running inside the same worker role ?

Comment: It's not just safe is needed if you want to achieve maximum throughput! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Queue is thread safe and is accessed using a REST API. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179363.aspx) has some reference data.